# Set a drawable overlay an imageview OnTouch android

Tags: android, imageview, ontouch

I hope some can help me. I am using `onTouch` method, I have a bitmat which I got from an `ImageView` which is displayed. Basically what I want to do is that when I touch the image then appear overlay other image (which I store in the drawable folder) in the same coordinates in which I touched.

I am pretty new with the `onTouch`method, and my problem is that when I touch my `ImageView` then my drawable replaces the `ImageView` i.e. it does not overlay.

I tried, comwthing with the `LayerDrawable`:

```
            Resources r = getResources();
            Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[1];
            layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.color_picker);
            LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

But when I touch the screen my app get an error and stop it.

Someone can help me for solve this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know it is too late but I answer this question so that it may be helpful.
I think you would better add another item to your "layers" Array.
so the code must be :

```
Resources r = getResources();
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.color_picker);
layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.yourFirstImage);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

I think this will work.